# How do I create a new class in IntelliJ without using the mouse?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to create a new class in a desired location without using the mouse in IntelliJ?

I understand there is no keyboard binding in the default keymap.

Comment: Please specify the operating system! Keyboard layouts are different for Windows/Linux and Mac.

Comment: Mac: `Command + 1` then `ctrl + return`

Comment: @Janac Meena that worked for me. PSA return key is the same as enter key on Mac. So basically Command+1 to navigate through the directory and then Ctrl+Enter to simulate "right clicking" and then creating a class/resource/etc.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

If you are already in the Project View, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> (**New**) | **Class**. Project View can be activated via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

To create a new class in the **same directory** as the current one use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> (**New...**).

You can also do it from the Navigation Bar, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>, then choose package with arrow keys, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Another useful shortcut is View | Select In (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), Project (<kbd>1</kbd>), then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to create a class near the existing one or use arrow keys to navigate through the packages.

And yet another way is to just type the class name in the existing code where you want to use it, IDEA will highlight it in red as it doesn't exist yet, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for the Intention Actions pop-up, choose **Create Class**.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder. You are indeed Crazy. BTW, are you crazy enough to use IntelliJ debugger without the mouse? It can not be done i tell you! I'm talking about full navigation around the debugging windows.

Comment: Probably you can't do everything with keyboard in debugger, but most things are possible. Alt+5 activates the panel, Tab switches between Frames/Variables/Watches, Up/Down in Frames changes frame, F2 in Variables edits variables, Insert in Watches adds Watch, other common keys also work (like delete/arrows, etc). Some actions have no default shortcuts and need to be assigned in Settings | Keymap.

Comment: I agree that not everything is possible with keyboard only with the debugger.

CrazyCoder, i challenge you to unplug your keyboard and work with IntelliJ!!!

Comment: Is there any way you know of to do it from code with a single keystroke? I've been trying to figure this out from time to time for years it seems.

Comment: @Blundell there are many keymaps provided, so I can't specify hotkeys for all of them, you just open your keymap settings or use `Help` | `Find Action` to figure out what is the shorcut for **New** action in your keymap.

Comment: What if the insert key does not work? The only insert key I have is on the number pad with 0, and Alt+Insert is not working.

Comment: @PeterBurbery you can change the shortcut in the Keymap settings: https://i.imgur.com/1vjGlA2.png.

Answer (score 109):

You can also use: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd>

Answer (score 24):

With <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Command + 1</kbd> you can navigate between project view and editor area - back and forward, in this way you can select the folder/location you need

With <kbd>Control +Option + N</kbd> you can trigger **New file** menu and select whatever you need, class, interface, file, etc. This works in editor as well in project view and it relates to the current selected location

*// please consider that this is working with standard key mapping*

Comment: This was helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

For Mac Os,  <kbd>command</kbd>  +  <kbd>1</kbd>  , then press  <kbd>control</kbd>  +  <kbd>return</kbd>

Answer (score 9):

On Mac OS 10.14.5, Idea Intellij 2019.1.3 - Press  <kbd>command</kbd>  +  <kbd>1</kbd>  to navigate to project files then press  <kbd>control</kbd>  +  <kbd>n</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

On Mac you can navigate to the location in Project view where you want to create your class and then use `⌘N` followed by `Enter`.

Answer (score 5):

I do this a lot, and I don't have an <kbd>insert</kbd> key on my laptop, so I made my own keybinding for it. You can do this by opening **Settings > IDE Settings > Keymap** and navigating to **Main menu > File > New...** (I would recommend typing "new" into the search box - that will narrow it down considerably).

Then you can add a new keyboard shortcut for it by double clicking on that item and selecting **Add Keyboard Shortcut**.

Answer (score 2):

1. Alt-Home until you're in Packages view
2. Down-arrow until package is highlighted
3. Alt-insert
4. Enter X 2
5. Type name
6. $PROFIT$

Answer (score 1):

If you use Mac, you are in luck. One can change the keymap for Intellij as Mac OS X, then you can use <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Which Intellij version, and did you use OSX keymap?

Answer (score 0):

In my (linux mint) system I can not get working combination <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd> so I do the next steps:

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (navigate to "tree") --> "context button - analog right mouse click" (between right <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>) -- then with arrows (up or down) desired choice (create new class or package or ...)

Hope it helps some "mint" owners )).

Answer (score 0):

I also searched this answer. Equivalent of command+N on Mac OS for Windows is ctr + alt + insert which @manyways already answered. If you searching this in settings it is in Settings > IDE Settings > Keymap, Other > New ...

Answer (score -2):

If the difficulty is in finding the option that makes .java or .class files (Like me), then simply,

click on the folder you want to create file on. select new, and type file's name along with extension.

For example, instead of, `helloWorld` type `helloworld.java` or any file extension you desire.