# Is there any way to create class without the help of mouse on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I'm just working on Mac OS X Lion, and totally fresh facing with the IntelliJ IDEA. Is there any easy way to create a class just with the keyboard, without the help of the mouse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i create a new class in IntelliJ without using the mouse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249494/how-do-i-create-a-new-class-in-intellij-without-using-the-mouse)

Comment: Same as post linked above except the different keyboard shortcut (can be verified with `Preferences` | `Keymap` or `Help` | `Find Action`). In the Mac default keymap it's `Ctrl+N` instead of `Alt+Insert` on Windows. See also http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-java-classes-interfaces-enumerations-and-annotations.html.

Comment: thank u so much...And i read the authority documentation from the intellij Idea.finally i got the solution.Thank u all the same.The solution is quite easy.Default keycap would be the control + alt + n,then i can choose the class to create.But i can't specify which class the new class would extends.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is

1. Navigate to the correct Java source directory in the Navigator. I do that by opening a class already in the module (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>), then use **Select Target**, **Project View** (<kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>) to jump to the right place in the Navigator.

[image]

2. Then the **Generate Code** command, both <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>) and <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> in the **Mac OS X 10.5+** keymap, will open the **New** pop up where you can type <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>... to get **Java**

[image]