# Anyone knows how to create a new Class on Intelij with shortcuts on a MAC?

Tags: macos, shortcut

That would be very appreciated, since I searched, and could only find for windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS: `CMD + 1` then `Control + Return`

First brings you to the main folder, then the next brings up a window to select what file type to create.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249494/how-do-i-create-a-new-class-in-intellij-without-using-the-mouse)

Comment: Didn't work. I even tried to create a shortcut to insert, but nothing.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: The latest, from their webPage... Downloaded last week!